# Tensorflow - uninitialized variable under tf.cond(...)

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow

I have an problem with tensorflow. I created a class for fully-connected layer with parameter in its constructor `is_hidden_layer` by which I decide to use or not to use relu and batch normalization on layer output. Code goes like this:

```
class FullLayer(object):
  def __init__(self, neurons, is_hidden_layer):
    self.is_hidden_layer = is_hidden_layer
    self.neurons = neurons

  def build(self, input):
    # ... uninteresting initialization code ... 
    W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([input_shape, self.neurons], stddev=0.1))
    b = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([self.neurons], stddev=0.1))
    hidden = tf.Variable(tf.constant(self.is_hidden_layer), name="is_hidden")
    output = tf.matmul(input, W) + b
    output = self.batch_norm(output)
    return tf.cond(tf.equal(hidden, True), lambda: tf.nn.relu(output), lambda: output)

  def batch_norm(self, input):
    with tf.variable_scope('batch_normalize'):
      mean = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.0, shape=[input.shape[-1]]),
                        trainable=True)
      # ... not interesting batch normalization code ...
```

This code works fine. But if change last two lines of `build` to this one:

```
return tf.cond(tf.equal(hidden, True), lambda: tf.nn.relu(self.batch_norm(output)), lambda: output)
```

(I put `batch_norm` under `cond`) I get an error:

> FailedPreconditionError (see above for traceback): Attempting to use
>   uninitialized value fc1/is_hidden      [[Node: fc1/is_hidden/read =
>   IdentityT=DT_BOOL, _class=["loc:@fc1/is_hidden"],
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]]

Exception is thrown here:

```
with tf.Session() as session:
  session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
```

When I replace `hidden` by `hidden.initialized_value()` I get the same error for variables in `batch_norm` method. I would make the same change there as well, but other side effects take place, e.g. `global_step` variable (variable I pass to AdamOptimizer to count steps) is not incremented and remains equal to 0 all the time. This is the thing I do not understand completely.

What is a reason behind this?

Comment: please let me know if you have found a solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55216779/tf-cond-on-a-variable-failedpreconditionerror-in-tf-global-variables-initialize